# Proper way to store a large list in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a table in my database to store a bunch of job related skills, similar to LinkedIn's skills and expertise feature.

How should I store the data?

I want to associate a job with a set of skills, but a lot of the skills overlap i.e. "supervisory skills", "management" etc. This skillset would then be associated with the appropriate user (I already have a table called `user`)

Should I create a table called "jobs", then create a column for each job type (maintenance, banking, customer service) followed by a second table called "skills" then add all the skills?

Obviously, I'm stuck. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @pst: 3 tables: `jobs`, `skills` and `jobs_has_skills` that will help avoid redundant data

Comment: You should study about representing many-to-many relationships in mysql. A quick web search will turn up lots of tutorials on this.

Comment: You can make many-to-many relation between job and skills, and use one table skills for users and jobs.

Comment: jobs <- jobskills -> skills, users <- userskills -> skills, no?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll do more research on many-to-many relationships. Just needed to know where to start looking

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid redundancy and dependency you should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables.

In your case that would mean 3 tables:

1. Jobs
2. Skills
3. Jobs_has_Skills